# Create subvi from output of loop

Tags: labview

Labview is very frusturating to me having used C/Java before.

I have a simple problem I dont know how to solve.

My program does some operations in a loop and updates an indicator inside the loop. I would like to make this loop (and the inputs it requires) into a VI but I have no idea how to make the indicator an output of the VI.

I would like to be able to reuse this VI, connect an indicator to it, and have it automatically update without creating any loops outside of the VI.

In C I would be able to do this by either returning a pointer or passing by reference to a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) The image below shows how to do this.
B) This style of programming works in small applications, but as an application grows larger, I would encourage you to explore an actual architecture for producing data in one hierarchy and consuming it in another (as alluded to by other answers to this question). In particular, do File >> Create Project and choose the Producer/Consumer template to explore a good starting point for such architectures. There are more sophisticated ones, but that makes an excellent beginning.
[image: Diagram transformations from original that updates a front panel terminal in a loop to the final that is a reusable subVI using a reference]

Comment: By the way: The reference to Current is created by right clicking on the FP terminal and choosing Create >> Reference.

Answer (score 3):

Use a **queue** to move data between loops in block diagrams.

The [producer/consumer](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3023/en/) pattern uses a queue to move the data between two loops on the *same* diagram, but a queue is global to a VI hierarchy and by [naming it when you create it](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/glang/create_queue/), a second VI can obtain a reference to it by using the same name.

*NB:* queues are 1:1 and lossless; if you need 1:N data transmission, use a [**notifier**](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/B9398355D9550EAF862566F20009DE19) (which is newest-value lossy) instead.

Answer (score 3):

In LabVIEW while loops have simple condition. The value can go outside the loop only when we will meet the condition. There is a condition terminal in the right down corner of the loop.

***At general:***

1) When true flag will be set there (stop if true) then the value will be passed outside the loop.

2) When the false flag will be set there (continue if true), then the value will be passed outside the loop.

3) You can always use error wires with condition terminal inside the loop, when error will be raised, then loop will stop.

***In your case:***
Always try to use the smallest amount of while loops as it is possible due to optimalization reason.

1) You can use while loop in your main VI, while all SubVIs will be in this loop and all values (indicators) will be updated.

2) You can try using while loops inside subVIs, but then you have to provide mechanisms that will transport values outside the loop such as [queues](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/DD7DBD9B10E3E537862565BC006CC2E4) or [local variables](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7585/en/)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a reference for a labview indicator as well, but you would need to make it a global variable or pass in the reference from the calling vi.

As for your frustrations, you should know that you can pretty much do anything in Labview that you can do in C.